# How would redirect the user mid way through a menu cycle using chevrons?

Tags: mobile, navigation, contextual-menu

[image: Mobile_navigation]
Action: selecting the chevron in the menu pushes more menu options to the left.

Scenario: A user wants to cycle through the menu items to see whats available. The user gets 3/4 of the way through and wants to go back to the beginning to view pricing.

Problem: The “Chevron” is still pointing to the right and won’t allow the user to go back to the beginning.

Question: We are already using a hamburger menu for the global navigation. The chevron solves the problem of cycling through the menu and when the user gets to the end a “Left chevron” appears allowing the user to go back.

My question is if the user is midway through the menu how do they get back to the beginning if the “left chevron” doesn’t display yet?

Comment: What problem does this menu solve that the hamburger menu doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not using the chevron at all.

A natural way for mobile users of scanning through large amounts of menu items is to allow them to scroll through or swipe items.

The perfect example is Google, if you visit the mobile version, the menu options beneath the search bar are swipeable/scrollable left and right. See how there is a fade on the right hand side to indicate to the user that this is scrollable list and the last item in the list is cut off.

[image]

If you absolutely must use a chevron because of implementation issues, why not include a chevron left and right of the nav? like so:

<   Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6   >

Comment: I agree with you, do away with the chevrons all together. That sort of design is pretty old school in my opinion (adding chevrons).

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting Android only?

If both Android and iOS, firstly, I'd encourage you to rethink using the hamburger menu. The hamburger menu has long ago been shown to have negative impacts:

https://lmjabreu.com/post/why-and-how-to-avoid-hamburger-menus/

I would strongly consider switching to a tab bar at least for iOS.

On to your question regarding chevrons - the typical way to have a set of tabs like this is to make it a swipeable ribbon - with no chevrons necessary.

A common technique for showing that there are more choices is to have only part of the text visible for the item that falls as the last tab in the default view - however this is difficult to control due to varying screen widths, localization etc.